# Hide html iframe using CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to be able to hide an iframe only using CSS, because I am not allowed to used any Javascript. The `iframe` should be hidden when a null result is returned to the `src`.
Is there any possible solution?

What I have till now (HTML):

```
<div class="mystyle">
    <iframe src="http://localhost:1000/content1"></iframe>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.mystyle {
   max-width: 100px; 
   max-height: 100px;

  & > iframe {
      max-width: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
    }

  & > iframe:empty {
    display: none;
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's not CSS, that's LESS. That also means that if you haven't transpiled it to actual CSS, it's not going to work.

Comment: ........or SCSS

Comment: The title maybe duplicate the actual question is not.  No it is not possible to use css only to hide the iframe if the src returns nothing. But the iframe will not be compromised by `display:none` so you can hide it and make it visible with JS when the src is not null.

Comment: Your iframe will always be ":empty" wether the source loads or nor. I don't think you can do this with CSS

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: I think he did, because he cant edit (or can he? ) because you close everything so fast.

Comment: The other question isn't closed. And yes op can edit their question

Comment: The problem is that the iframe still takes space although there is no content in it. Is that the normal behavioral?

Comment: @Turnip I thought that my question wasn't clear enough that's why I have post another question, you are right it's a duplicate, can I delete one of them? Thank you